# Mac 64-bit compiler constants

Tags: macos, excel, vba

Microsoft has just updated Excel 2016 to 64-bit on OSX (yay!).  But now they have broken add-in support on OSX.  First problem:

Q: How do I conditionally compile/include code on Excel 2016 for OSX?  On windows they have separate flags for 32-bit and 64-bit, so you can do something like:

```
#If Win64 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function get_global_param_string_private Lib "CoolProp_xls_x64.dll" Alias "get_global_param_string" (ByVal param As String, ByVal Output As String, ByVal n As Integer) As Long
#Else
Private Declare Function get_global_param_string_private Lib "CoolProp_xls_std.dll" Alias "_get_global_param_string@12" (ByVal param As String, ByVal Output As String, ByVal n As Integer) As Long
#End If
```

but according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264614.aspx, there is no separate VBA constant to differentiate between bitness on OSX?  What compiler constants have they added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditions, like this:

```
#If Win64 Then

#ElseIf Win32 Then

#ElseIf Mac Then
    #If MAC_OFFICE_VERSION >= 15 Then
        #If VBA7 Then ' 64-bit Excel 2016 for Mac

        #Else ' 32-bit Excel 2016 for Mac

        #End If
    #Else ' 32-bit Excel 2011 for Mac

    #End If
#End If
```

Comment: Nice!!! Any idea on my other very-related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39813612/excel-2016-conditional-compilation-with-32-bit-flags ?

Comment: See also https://github.com/OfficeDev/VBA-content/blob/master/VBA/Office-Mac-VBA/MacOfficeVersion.md