# Excel 2016 conditional compilation with 32-bit flags

Tags: macos, excel, excel-2016, vba

In the new 64-bit version of Excel 2016 on OSX I obtained through update today, the conditional compilation doesn't seem to be followed when checking for function definitions that don't have PtrSafe defined (as would be the case for 32-bit platforms).  In this example, we have different definitions of the same function for different platforms, and when Excel loads the add-in it dies and complains about the third definition not having a PtrSafe in the function declaration (but of course it doesn't because it is for a 32-bit platform).

Is there any way of making Excel not die when it hits this code in VBA?  Or is this just a bug in 64-bit Excel 2016 on OSX?  Seems like an obvious bug to me. Where do I report bugs in Excel?

```
#If Mac Then
' Even though the functions are exported with a leading underscore, Excel 2011 for Mac doesn't want the leading underscore as part of name
Private Declare PtrSafe Function get_global_param_string_private Lib "libCoolProp.dylib" Alias "get_global_param_string" (ByVal param As String, ByVal Output As String, ByVal n As Integer) As Long
#ElseIf Win64 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function get_global_param_string_private Lib "CoolProp_xls_x64.dll" Alias "get_global_param_string" (ByVal param As String, ByVal Output As String, ByVal n As Integer) As Long
#Else
Private Declare Function get_global_param_string_private Lib "CoolProp_xls_std.dll" Alias "_get_global_param_string@12" (ByVal param As String, ByVal Output As String, ByVal n As Integer) As Long
#End If
```

[image: This is the error from Excel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the API function itself is different for 64 and 32 bit windows it suffices to use the VBA7 switch (which starts at Office 2010) for Windows:

```
#If Mac Then
' Even though the functions are exported with a leading underscore, Excel 2011 for Mac doesn't want the leading underscore as part of name
Private Declare PtrSafe Function get_global_param_string_private Lib "libCoolProp.dylib" Alias "get_global_param_string" (ByVal param As String, ByVal Output As String, ByVal n As Integer) As Long
#ElseIf VBA7 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function get_global_param_string_private Lib "CoolProp_xls_x64.dll" Alias "get_global_param_string" (ByVal param As String, ByVal Output As String, ByVal n As Integer) As Long
#Else
Private Declare Function get_global_param_string_private Lib "CoolProp_xls_std.dll" Alias "_get_global_param_string@12" (ByVal param As String, ByVal Output As String, ByVal n As Integer) As Long
#End If
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, which related to excels confusion about functions that do not have a ptrsafe because they are for 32 bit platforms

Comment: if you're using Excel 2010 or later the ptrsafe keyword can be used on any bitness. See http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/apideclarations.asp for more info.

Comment: I didn't know that that!! Thanks for the info about the versions that this is supported in